# Xcode: Resetting View Controller Size

Tags: ios, xcode

I created a second view controller for the purpose of creating a popover modal when I click on a button.  I tried changing the size of the controller by going to Utilities and:

[image]

[image]

This correctly changes the size of the view controller but when I switch it back to fixed, it doesn't reset the storyboard size to the default size, how do I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot choose a custom size (like `200x50`) in `fixed` mode. So, if you want to have this size, you have to stay un `simulated` mode.

But, be careful: this is just the **simulated** size of your view. It does not define the real size of your view when your code will be executed. executed.

Comment: Ah, I see, how would I define the actual popover window size?

Comment: I think you should have a look on how constraints works. Here is a good point to start: 
https://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1